# Finding duplicate words within a string regex C/W

Tags: java, regex, string, duplicates, words

I'm currently dabbing in regex in Java, and want to try and find duplicate words in strings. If I inputted a string such as 'This this is great.'. I was using `\\b(\\w+) \\1\\b`, but that only recognizes two duplicate words, such as 'this this' in a string.

Any help regarding this?

Comment: Why do you want to use regex for this? You could just convert to a String array using split and then there are many options for figuring out the duplicate words

Comment: If you're truly just begining to _dabble_ in regex, this is probably too complicated of a place to start... Not to mention the fact that regex is probably the wrong tool for the job.  This would be **a lot** easier to do with the basic string methods.

Comment: I should of said before, but I am doing these regex examples for my college/university course, and this example is the only one left. I've been stumped on it for hours!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the "ignore case" switch `(?i)` to your regex:

```
(?i)\\b(\\w+) \\1\\b
```

Alternatively, you could fold the input to lower case first:

```
input.toLowerCase()
```

Note: If you're using `String.matches()`, the regex must match the *entire* input, so you'd add `.*` to both ends of your regex:

```
.*(?i)\\b(\\w+) \\1\\b.*
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, it works with the two words side-by-side. But 'This this doesn't work' doesn't.

Comment: Those words are side by side ;-)

Comment: I understand that :P, just when I use more than two words in a string, it doesn't recognize that both words (that are next to each other) are the same word.

Comment: Got it.  That's not how I would interpret "_side by side_".  Now it makes more sense.

Comment: If you're using this regex with `String.matches()`, see note at bottom of answer

Comment: Cheers Bohemian! Works how I want it now!

Answer (score 1):

```
String pattern = "\\b(\\w+)(\\b\\W+\\b\\1\\b)*"; 
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

You can use `Matcher.group()` and `Matcher.group(1)` to replace all duplicate words with this approach.